# Conjugacy classes of GL(3, 2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I need to find all conjugacy classes of *GL(3, 2)* in order to determine their cardinality and give a representative for each of them.

I know that the number of conjugacy classes should be 6 and that one of these is surely the one containing just the identity. However, I don't understand how to find the five remaining. I understood the definition of conjugacy classes, but I don't know how to proceed; since we have 168 elements in the group I don't think I should just try randomly.

Can someone please explain me what should I do, if there is a strategy or something?

Also, I ask you please not to be rude even if the answer is obvious or easy. I'm not very good at Algebra and so I'd like to have detailed answers in order to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [the solution](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43678571?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Comment: Thank you, I think I finally understood! If I got it right there should be one class of order 1, one of order 21, two with order 24, one of order 42 and the last one of 56. Using the _class equation_ we find that their sum is 168, which is the order of GL(3, 2). Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: You can also find an answer in [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3361134/669).

Comment: Thanks @j.p. I hadn't found this question during my research and so I asked mine, but now that I see it I find it very useful!